# Service is getting Reinitialized Upon URL Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to store and get an object in my service however when I navigate to URL through `$window.location.href`, my service is getting reinitialized so I lose what I had stored.

My Service Code

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('app.services')
        .factory('myService', Service);

    Service.$inject = ['$http'];

    function Service($http) {

        var myData = {};

        return {

            setmyData: function(data) {
                myData = JSON.parse(data);
            },

            getmyData: function() {
                return myData;
            }
        }

    }
})();
```

Comment: That is by design, Use `$location` services `.path()`/`.url()` method.

Comment: ok thanks @Satpal i'll give it a try!

Comment: That Worked! Thanks @Satpal